# In jQuery-ui, this._mouseInit is not a function error, why am I getting this after i upgrade to 1.8.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Hi I am having trouble with my application after I upgraded to 1.8.2 jquery-ui.  I am getting a "this._mouseInit is not a function error".

Includes:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css" media="all">@import "css/pinpoint.css";</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.pinpoint.js"></script>
```

Here is where the code is giving me the error:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $.widget("ui.boxTool", $.extend({}, $.ui.mouse, {

  _init: function() {
    this.element.addClass("ui-boxTool");
    this.dragged = false;

    this._mouseInit();
    this.width = $('#toPinpoint').width();
    this.height = $('#toPinpoint').height();

    this.helper = $(document.createElement('div'))
      .css({border:'1px dashed #c2c0c0'})
      .css({cursor:'crosshair'})
      .addClass("ui-boxTool-helper");
  },

  destroy: function() {
    this.element
      .removeClass("ui-boxTool ui-boxTool-disabled")
      .removeData("boxTool")
      .unbind(".selectable");
    this._mouseDestroy();

    return this;
  },

  _mouseStart: function(event) {
    var self = this;

    this.opos = [event.pageX, event.pageY];

    if (this.options.disabled)
      return;

    var options = this.options;

    this._trigger("start", event);

    $(options.appendTo).append(this.helper);

    this.helper.css({
      "z-index": 100,
      "position": "absolute",
      "left": event.clientX,
      "top": event.clientY,
      "width": 0,
      "height": 0
    });
  },

  _mouseDrag: function(event) {
    var self = this;
    this.dragged = true;

    if (this.options.disabled)
      return;

    var offset = $('.canvas').offset();
    var options = this.options;
    var x1 = this.opos[0], y1 = this.opos[1], x2 = event.pageX, y2 = event.pageY;
    if (x1 > x2) { 
        var tmp = x2; 
        x2 = x1; 
        x1 = tmp; 
    }
    if (y1 > y2) { var tmp = y2; y2 = y1; y1 = tmp; }
    if (x2 > this.width+offset.left-1){x2=this.width+offset.left-1;}
    if (y2 > this.height+offset.top-1){y2=this.height+offset.top-1;}
    if (x1 < offset.left){x2=this.offset.left;}
    if (y1 < offset.top){ x2=this.offset.top;}
    this.helper.css({left: x1, top: y1, width: x2-x1, height: y2-y1});

    this._trigger("drag", event);

    return false;
  },

  _mouseStop: function(event) {
    var self = this;

    this.dragged = false;

    var options = this.options;

    var clone = this.helper.clone()
      .removeClass('ui-boxTool-helper').appendTo(options.appendTo);



    this._trigger("stop", event, { box: clone });

    this.helper.remove();
    //$('.view-mode').remove(this.helper);
    return false;
  }

  }));
});
```

Comment: Which files are you including in the page? The entire jQuery UI library or only parts?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? That was made for the latest jQuery library so you need to make sure you're using the latest version of that as well.

Comment: @Nick Craver @Kerry hey added the includes! thanks

Comment: This is a duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902468/this-mouseinit-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 2):

The syntax changed a bit in jQuery UI 1.8+ when extending a widget, this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $.widget("ui.boxTool", $.extend({}, $.ui.mouse, {
```

Should just be this:

```
$.widget("ui.boxTool", $.ui.mouse, {
```

Two changes here: the [`$.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) isn't needed, it's determined by the arguments now, and you don't want to declare plugins inside a `window.onload` event...there's no need and it'll only cause trouble.

---

Make sure to change the end to match as well, the last 2 lines:

```
  }));
});
```

Should now just be:

```
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you may want to check this out:
http://jqueryui.com/docs/Changelog/1.8

on the page seach for: "mouse new file"

mouse functions has been separated from the core